# How to truncate a 2's complement output

Tags: type-conversion

I have data written into *short* data type. The data written is of 2's complement form.
Now when I try to print the data using %04x, the data with MSB=0 is printed fine for eg if data=740, print I get is 0740
But when the MSB=1, I am unable to get a proper print. For eg if data=842, print I get is fffff842
I want the data truncated to 4 bytes so expected output is f842

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming C (or possibly C++) as the language here.

Because of the default argument promotions involved when calling a variable argument function (such as `printf`), your use of a `short` will result in an *integer promotion*, which states that *"If an **int** can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an **int**"*.

A `short` is converted to an `int` by means of sign-extension, and 0xf842 sign-extended to 32 bits is 0xfffff842.

You can use a bitwise AND to mask off the most significant word:

```
printf("%04x", data & 0xffff);
```

You could also add the `h` length specifier to state that you only want to print an (unsigned) `short` worth of bits from an `int`:

```
printf("%04hx", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either declare your data as a type which is 16 bits long, or make sure the printing function uses the right format for 16 bits value. Or use your current type, but do a bitwise AND with `0xffff`. What you can do depends on the language you're doing it in really.

But whichever way you go, check your assumptions again. There seems to be a few issues in your question:

- 2s-complement applies to signed numbers only. There are no negative numbers in your question.
- Assuming you mean C's `short` - it doesn't have to be 16 bits long.
- "I get is fffff842 I want the data truncated to 4 bytes" - `fffff842` is 4 bytes long. `f842` is 2 bytes long.
- 2-bytes long value `842` does not have the MSB set.